# Fab is sitting too low

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I have a Fab that is anchored to a Bottom App Bar. When a Snack bar appears the Fab moves up like it should, but when  the Snack bar disappears the Fab returns to a lower position. after a few seconds it returns to its proper position but I can't figure out why it sinks lower for those few seconds. how can I fix it? I can't post my code right now, but I was curious if there were any obvious answers.. thanks.

```
   <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_bar_menu">

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_bar"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Snackbar.make(v, "Test", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Welcome here.. in order to have support from someone here you should provide the code you tried.

Comment: @OP perhaps you should provide a gif of the behavior so that people can see what you're saying. Kind of hard to tell. But from what you're specifying it sounds like your FAB is changing position because of potential position manipulation happening programatically, or it has to do with with your Activity and Fragment and associating FAB with the fragment vs the activity. You should try isolating your FAB behavior into a test app for further validation. Isolate the individual factors to know where you should focus.

Comment: I threw this together just to test its behavior, and it does the same.  But I guess snack bar shouldn't cover bottom app bar anyway? In that case if I set fab as anchor for snack bar it shows above fab.